# Android Call Fragment Method from Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 4 Fragments and I am trying to click a button on FragmentA and call a method that changes the visibility of some views on FragmentB and populate it.

I tried an interface, but I can't seem to get it to work between 2 fragments. I can call the interface method from a fragment if I implement it in the activity, but I can't implement it in a fragment and call it in a fragment.

Is there a different way to do this? I don't think I can use the static keyword.

Comment: you can either use shared preferences to store  data and  change them according to your fragments

Comment: The Activity implements the interface and calls the appropriate method of the Fragment, please show the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suggesting you can use broadcast receiver its, good to perform action anywhere and easy to use.
In your first fragment you can define receiver and from another fragment, you can send broadcast or action.

Example are following.

Write following code in your first fragment in which  you want to update view,

```
private void registerReciver() {
        broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent != null && intent.getAction().equals("UPDATE_FRAG_A")) {
                    // here you can fire your action which you want also get data from intent
                }
            }
        };
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("UPDATE_FRAG_A");
        getActivity().registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    }
```

And In your second fragment write following code for fire action,

```
Intent intent=new Intent();
        // Here you can also put data on intent
        intent.setAction("UPDATE_FRAG_A");
        getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: Is there a nice guide or tutorial you could point me in. They seem pretty complicated. I feel like I did this all wrong as I need to manipulate Views from my fragment and if my Activity had access to them this would be simple.

Comment: I updated my answer please check now, and please don't miss to unregister broadcast receiver in your first fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that all the fragments are in the same activity.

1. Define a interface in FragmentA, which is a Listener
2. Expose what you want to do in FragmentB via a public method
3. Implement FragmentA's interface in the parent activity by calling the public method of FragmentB

For more inforamtion,see [Communicating with Other Fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Could you give an example? I cannot get it to work from Fragment to Fragment. I can do Activity to Fragment and vice versa, but not Fragment to Fragment.